# Grouping One column's all values in one list on basis of some other column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, grouping

here, I want to group all the values in column `cont_name` based on column `ticker` .

For Example below dataset:-

[image]

I want the output to be like:-

[image]

As you can see the `cont_name` column's values have been appended by grouping on `ticker`

Comment: Please do not post photos of data or code! If you do, people who are willing to help you would have to type out all that text. Instead provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes noted! thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with dario in the comments, but it's easy to solve with `group_by` and `paste`:

```
library(tidyverse)

cont <- tibble(
  ticker = c(rep('000001-SHE', 6), '000002-SHE', rep('000046-SHE', 2)), 
  cont_name = c('Bribery and Corruption', 'Business Ethics', 'Corporate Governance', 'Quality and Safety', 'Social Impacts of Products', 'Carbon Impacts of Products', 'Quality and Safety', 'Business Ethics', 'Labour Relations')
)

cont %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  summarize(cont_name = paste(cont_name, collapse = ','))
```